# zipWith (++) an arbitrary number of lists

Tags: haskell

I have to zip n lists with (++). I have found no better way to do that define this operator on lists:

```
 (+++) = zipWith (\x y -> x ++ " " ++ y)
```

There is a better solution?

**After Markus1189 answer**, I formulate a more general question: does exist a function like this:

```
zipNWith f2 [a] = f2 (f2 x1 x2) x3 ... f2 (xn-2 xn-1) xn?
```

---

This is the program which is used the operator ( +++)

```
csoundLines instrs inits durs amps freqs = putStrLn . unlines $
    repeat "i" +++ ms instrs +++ ms inits +++ ms durs +++ ms amps +++ ms freqs
  where
  (+++) = zipWith (\x y -> x ++ " " ++ y)
  ms xs = map show xs

scaleNTonic n = map (\i -> 440 * 2 ** (i/n)) [0..n]
```

-- example: csoundLines (repeat 1) [0.5, 1 ..] (repeat 0.5) (repeat 0.3) $ scaleNTonic 6

```
> i 1 0.5 0.5 0.3 440.0
> i 1 1.0 0.5 0.3 493.8833012561241
> i 1 1.5 0.5 0.3 554.3652619537442
> i 1 2.0 0.5 0.3 622.2539674441618
> i 1 2.5 0.5 0.3 698.4564628660078
> i 1 3.0 0.5 0.3 783.9908719634985
> i 1 3.5 0.5 0.3 880.0
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: There is a more elegant solution? Or an operator already defined in some package? (i did not found). Something like nZipWith (++), similar to fold...

Comment: Are you aware of [ZipList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:ZipList)?. Perhaps it's what you are looking for. There are some examples in the [Applicative Functors chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) of LYAH

Comment: If I try:getZipList $ (++) <$> ZipList ["dog","cat"] <*> ZipList ["cat","dog"] the result is ok : ["dogcat","catdog"]
but if I try: getZipList $ (++) <$> ZipList ["dog","cat"] <*> ZipList ["cat","dog"] <*> ["rat","rat"], I get an error. How should I change (++) to obtain a valid result? (Not it seems to me that there is an easy solution.)

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani, the first function on the applicative expression takes as many arguments as applicative arguments passed. `(++)` takes 2 arguments and there are 3 lists so you should use a function that takes 3 arguments, for example `(\x y z -> x ++ y ++ z) <$> ...`

Comment: @DannyNavarro, getZipList $ (\x y z -> x ++ y ++ z) <$> ZipList ["dog","cat"] <*> ZipList ["cat","dog"] <*> ["rat","rat"] generates this error message: Couldn't match type `[]' with `ZipList'
    Expected type: ZipList [Char]
      Actual type: [[Char]]
    In the second argument of `(<*>)', namely `["rat", "rat"]'
    In the second argument of `($)',...

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani, you are missing the last `ZipList` in `["rat","rat"]`

Comment: `map unwords . transpose`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use a fold for arbitrary number of lists:

```
>>> foldr1 (zipWith (++)) [["dog","cat"],["cat","dog"],["rat","rat"]]
["dogcatrat","catdograt"]
```

Or with space in between:

```
>>> foldr1 (zipWith (\x y -> x ++ " " ++ y)) [["dog","cat"],["cat","dog"],["rat","rat"]]
["dog cat rat","cat dog rat"]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to process an arbitrary amount of lists is to put them all in a list:

```
import Data.List
zipAll :: [[String]] -> [String]
zipAll = map unwords . transpose

ghci> zipAll [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["xx", "yy", "zz"]]
["a 1 xx","b 2 yy","c 3 zz"]
```

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to pass them as separate arguments (which number is undefined), but you could probably use an approach of [printf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf).

Comment: I had tried a similar solution (map concat . transpose), but will not function if some lists are endless, as in my example. Instead zip "cut" the result on the list shorter, so it is necessary that there is only one finit list to work properly.

Comment: `transpose` works with infinite lists, the result will be infinite too and you can `take` desired number of elements, e.g. minimum of lengths of the input lists.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is nothing wrong with your approach.  If one was really concerned about performance, I would change it slightly to:

```
(+++) = zipWith (\x y -> x ++ (' ' : y))
```

so that you avoid the `" " ++ <long list>`.

There is also [ZipList](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors#ZipLists), but you would have to pass it an function that takes the exact number of arguments you give it, which I guess is not what you want. Yuuri's answer does also work, but as said above there is nothing wrong with your function.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I reformulate slightly my question: I will make a slightly more general my question: Is there a predefined function of the type: zipNWith f2 [a] = f2 (f2 x1 x2) x3 ... f2 (xn-2 xn-1) xn?